# Increasing count on click for custom Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with a custom Library in React, where you can add emojis, And I'm trying to make a counter variable to the object, which increases each time a user clicks on it.

The point is to make it into an array, of several emojis, but so far, I'm trying to make it work with only one.

So I have a condition rather the emoji should be shown or not

```
{
  this.state.showEmoji &&
    <div className="emoji">
      <Emoji 
        onClick={this.increment}
        emoji={{ id: this.state.emoji.id, skin: 1, }}
        size={25}
      />
      <p>{this.state.emoji.count}</p>
    </div>
}
```

Inside I render my Emoji along with the counter, which determinates how many times the emoji has been rendered/clicked

I'm not sure if I should make an anonymous function or make a handler, I tried out with the handler

I have made a custom emoji object in my state (which will eventually be an array of emoji objects)

```
emoji: {
  id: '',
  count: 0,
}
```

Along with my increment handler method:

```
increment = (emoji) =>{
  console.log(emoji.id);
  console.log(this.state.emoji.id);
  this.setState({
   count: this.state.emoji[emoji.id].count++
  });
}
```

I successfully console log the emoji objects state id and then passed in emoji object, and they match.

But when I try to mutate the state I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
```

Why can't I access the object with the id in this case?

Comment: What do you think is going to happen with `this.state.emoji[emoji.id]`?

Comment: I was wondering if it would access the object, but since there is only one, i don't think it will be necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
increment = (emoji) =>{
 const { emoji } = this.state; // isn't that more readable?
 const _emoji = {
   ...emoji,
   count: emoji.count + 1
 } //this will create a copy of your emoji object.
   // use +1 instead of ++ to make sure you are keeping the original count value as it is, 'PURE PROGRAMMING'
 this.setState({ emoji: _emoji });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/l5o0r54wvq), it may help with managing the array of emojis as well.